# Question About the Integration of rational function

Tags: integration

I was asked to dismantle this rational function by parts and wanted to know if I did it right.
The function is: 
$${\frac{x^5-x+3}{x(x-2)^3(x^2+2x+2)}}$$

What I did is:
$$\frac{A}{X}+\frac{B}{(x-2)}+\frac{C}{(x-2)^2}+\frac{D}{(x-2)^3}+\frac{GX+C}{x^2+2x+2}$$

Thanks!

Comment: Correct, except for writing $X$ for $x$ sometimes.  And the last numerator should involve two new constsnts, not the $C$ already used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @GEdgar pointed out, there are some minor issues (uppercase X terms and use two different variable names for the last term). Change the last term to something like $Ex + F$.

After expansion and solving, you should get:

- $\displaystyle A = -3$
- $\displaystyle B = \frac{1983}{2000}$
- $\displaystyle C = \frac{427}{200}$
- $\displaystyle D = \frac{33}{20}$
- $\displaystyle E = \frac{49}{250}$
- $\displaystyle F = \frac{137}{500}$

Comment: Nice work! Provides the OP with the chance to check his/her work!

Comment: What? I didn't nominate myself! I don't plan to run!